# ContentVersion queries omitting recent records unless queried by an ID field

Tags: soql, contentversion, summer-21

We are seeing a very strange behavior in a Summer '21 sandbox.  Queries for `ContentVersion` will not return "recently" created records, unless queried by an ID or relationship.  For example:

```
SELECT Id, CreatedDate FROM ContentVersion ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

Shows a most-recent CreatedDate of 5 days ago, but

```
SELECT Id, CreatedDate FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId = '06929000001KMpjAAG'
```

Shows several CVs which were created yesterday/today. Likewise,

```
SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId 
  FROM ContentVersion 
 WHERE (Pending_Deletion_Date__c != NULL AND Pending_Deletion_Date__c <= TODAY)
```

Returns no records, but

```
SELECT Id, Pending_Deletion_Date__c
  FROM ContentVersion
 WHERE ContentDocumentId = '06929000001KMpjAAG'
```

Returns multiple records with `Pending_Deletion_Date__c == TODAY` (and which were created yesterday or today).

Has anyone seen this behavior?  Any explanation other than a new bug?

**Edit to add**: Confirmed that non-id queries only return records created before the Summer 21 update was installed to the Sandbox.  Posted to Release Readiness Trailblazers: https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/0D54S00000B5cFp

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, I'd recommend talking to support/your account rep, and possibly posting over in the Release Readiness Trailblazers group: https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/featuredGroupDetail?id=a1z30000006IDYhAAO .  There have been some funky issues popping up for Summer '21 that have apparently merited emergency fixes - I haven't seen this one talked about yet but others there may have experienced it.